# Rails STI—can I get the value of 'type' directly from db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I'm changing a model so that it no longer uses Single Table Inheritance. I deleted the subclasses, and I made a migration that does:

```
add_column :discounts, :name, :string
Discount.all.each do |discount|
  discount.update(name: discount.type)
end
```

This crashes with the following error:

```
The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'RetailerStaffFlatRate'
```

Instead of using `discount.type`, am I able to simply grab the value stored in the db, so the model doesn't crash?

Comment: Do you need to keep `type` column? If no, renaming the column name can help, something like  `rename_column :discounts, :type, :name`

Comment: does the class RetailerStaffFlatRate still exist in the sources?

Comment: No I deleted it. I could try restore it, but I'm interested to know if you can get the db field directly without triggering any active record stuff

Answer (score 0):

In your parent model you can define a method to get them:

`def self.types
    unscoped.select(:type).distinct.pluck(:type)
  end`

Then just use `Discount.types` and you'll get an array with the present types.

*NOTE* This approach only lists the types present on the database